# what does <meta - data> mean?

Tags: java, android

I cannot figure out why I have to use two meta-data elements in my manifest in order to get to work my Google Maps API v2 project.
What is the purpose of these tags?

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta Data means data about the data.

Answer (score 0):

`meta-data` provides a way to add information for third-party components to the AndroidManifest.xml, that must not be defined by the Android SDK.
Metadata elements are not expected to be defined by the Android API.

The [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html) say:

`A name-value pair for an item of additional, arbitrary data...`

Answer (score 0):

A *meta-data* tag contains a key-value pair holding information about your app's package, which is relevant to other packages (usually just other apps).

This data is exposed to those packages through the PackageManager.

This is a quick and easy way to share pre-determined data between package, synchronously. 
The other way would be through intents, which requires considerable amount of coding, is asynchronous and prone to break on API changes.

([docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html))